# Possible to set the computer uptime, either globally or for the current process?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.8

`Environment.TickCount` reports the number of milliseconds since the system started. The value starts at 0, then cycles between `Int32.MaxValue` and `Int32.MinValue` with a total cycle time of ~49.7 days.

Is it possible to tell Windows *"You've now been running for X days!"*, probably safest for the current process (not system-wide)? The intention is to test code relying on `TickCount` regardless of the system uptime.

Comment: Use the chk build. That artificially sets the computer uptime to an hour before 32-bit rollover, specifically so you can test this case.

Comment: Don't think so. It goes all the way to `GetTickCount` in Win32, I would imagine you need to interact with the System Clock device driver to do anything like that

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such cases is abstract out the given API via an interface and implement different providers. Something like this:

```
public interface ITickCount
{
    int TickCount { get; }
}

public class TestingTickCountProvider : ITickCount
{
    public int Base { get; set; }
    public int TickCount => Base + Environment.TickCount;
}
```

Then inject the provider via an IoC container.

The same principle is useful for abstracting out the current user, current date and time, culture info, etc.